# Need help to optimize dynamic programming problem solution

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

> The problem statement:
>
> Given two arrays `a` and `b` with sizes `n` and `m` respectively. All numbers in these arrays are in the range of 0 to 9 inclusive. Lets create a matrix with size of `n x m` where values in row `i` and column `j` is equal to `ai * 10^9 + bj`. Find the path from square `1,1` to `n,m` with the maxium sum. You're allowed to move forward or down.
>
> Input parameters:
> The first line contains `n` and `m` (1 <= n, m <= 100 000)
>
> The second line contains values of array `a`
>
> The third line contains values of array `b`
>
> Output
> Print the maximum sum
>
> Time limit: 1 second
>
> Memory limit: 512MB

Example:

input:

```
7 4
0 7 1 7 6 7 6
4 1 9 7
```

output: `55000000068`

[image]

I tried to solve this problem with dynamic programming, but my solution works in `O(n * m)` and can't pass time limit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        int n, m; cin >> n >> m;

        vector<uint64_t> a(n), b(m);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int tmp;
             cin >> tmp;
             a[i] = tmp * 10e8;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) cin >> b[i];

        vector<uint64_t> dp(m);
        dp[0] = a[0] + b[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
            dp[i] = dp[i-1] + a[0] + b[i];

        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
                if (j == 0)
                    dp[j] = dp[j] + a[i] + b[j];
                else
                    dp[j] = max(dp[j], dp[j-1]) + a[i] + b[j];
            }
        }

        cout << dp.back() << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but, using a recursive function with memoisation might solve it. It is because in recursive function you don't fill the entire matrix.

Comment: if you can move forward or down wouldn't that mean that you need two indices for your optimal solution? For example, square (2,3) can be arrived at either from (1,3) or from (2,2)

Comment: @HikmatFarhat yes, you're right. But greedy aproach will not work here.

Comment: @maksadbek I did not mean greedy. Your recursive formula should be of the form opt[i][j]=max(opt[i-1][j]+val, opt[i][j-1]+someval)

Comment: @HikmatFarhat what does someval mean ? I used a 1D array in my solution because with 2D array we won't pass the memory limit

Comment: @maksadbek If you use one dimension then what does dp[j] refer to? For example the value of dp[4]  which square which square does it refer to??

Comment: @HikmatFarhat As we need to move forward and down, we only need to keep optimal solution for prev and upper squares. For j = 0, dp[j] is upper square value. For the next squares dp[j] is upper and dp[j-1] is prev squares. Try to run my solution with example I provided and you will understand it.

Comment: @r3mainer you're right, it is a typo, will fix it now

Comment: Note that this problem is not symmetric: you get more "points" by staying on rows with a large digit. The problem is then "when do you jump from one large row to the next".

Comment: Aside: `int tmp; cin >> tmp; a[i] = tmp * 10e8;` may run into precision problem as the multiplication does not use 64-bit integer math.  Suggest `uint64_t tmp;`  OTOH, perhaps OK with restrictive  0-9 `tmp` values.

Comment: well, I think the key is that a is more important than b and it will be solved with some greedy.

Comment: Try to use the fact that a*10^9 dominates b.

Comment: @Surt how can you ever get more than 55 in the most significant digits?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. by mistaking a for b?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to solve this problem without dynamic programming, and with O(n+m) memory and time requirements.

As pointed out by [@Botje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548468/botje) in the comments, the reward for higher values in *a* is overwhelmingly large. An optimal path will therefore remain in the leftmost column until it reaches the largest value in *a* (which is 7 in the above example). If this maximum value appears only once in *a*, then the best option would be to consume the whole of this row, followed by the last elements of all the following rows until we reach the bottom right corner.

However, if this maximum value appears more than once, we can get a better score by moving right along the first row with the maximum value of *a* until we reach a column with the maximum value of *b*, then moving down this column to the last row containing the maximum value of *a*. We can then consume the rest of this row followed by the last elements of all following rows as before.

Perhaps an illustration will help:

```
    a = [ 0, 6, 9, 9, 0, 9, 3, 1 ]
    b = [ 1, 3, 2, 8, 4, 8, 1, 6 ]

   Col:  0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
  Row:
   0    0,1   0,3   0,2   0,8   0,4   0,8   0,1   0,6 
         v
   1    6,1   6,3   6,2   6,8   6,4   6,8   6,1   6,6 
         v 
   2    9,1 > 9,3 > 9,2 > 9,8   9,4   9,8   9,1   9,6 
                           v
   3    9,1   9,3   9,2   9,8   9,4   9,8   9,1   9,6 
                           v
   4    0,1   0,3   0,2   0,8   0,4   0,8   0,1   0,6 
                           v
   5    9,1   9,3   9,2   9,8 > 9,4 > 9,8 > 9,1 > 9,6 
                                                   v
   6    3,1   3,3   3,2   3,8   3,4   3,8   3,1   3,6 
                                                   v
   7    1,1   1,3   1,2   1,8   1,4   1,8   1,1   1,6
```

In this example, there are three rows where *a* = 9, which are rows 2, 3 and 5. To get the maximum score, we need to follow the first of these rows (i.e. row 2) until we reach the column with the maximum value of *b* (either column 3 or column 5, it makes no difference). Then move down to the last row where *a*=9 (row 5), step right to the end of this row, and finally down to the bottom right corner.

I've converted the Python code from an earlier version of this answer into C++. In tests with 10<sup>5</sup> random values in arrays *a* and *b*, it produces a result in about 0.3 seconds on my system. The dynamic programming solution above gives identical results, but takes about 4 minutes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;

    vector<int64_t> a(n), b(m);
    int tmp, astart, aend, bmax, i, j;
    
    // Read in arrays a[] and b[]. At the same time,
    // find the first and last indices of the maximum
    // value in a[] (astart and aend) and any index
    // corresponding to the maximum value of b[] (bmax)
    
    for (tmp = -1, i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
        if (a[i] >= tmp) {
            aend = i;
            if (a[i] > tmp) {
                astart = i;
                tmp = a[i];
            }
        }
        a[i] *= 1000000000LL;
    }
    for (tmp = -1, j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        cin >> b[j];
        if (b[j] > tmp) {
            tmp = b[j];
            bmax = j;
        }
    }
    
    // Trace through the matrix. First work down as far as
    // astart, then right until column bmax. Then work down
    // as far as row aend, add the remaining elements in this
    // row, and finally add the last element of each remaining
    // rows until we reach the bottom right corner.
    
    i = j = 0;
    int64_t tot = a[i] + b[j];
    while (i < astart) tot += a[++i] + b[j];
    while (j < bmax) tot += a[i] + b[++j];
    while (i < aend) tot += a[++i] + b[j];
    while (j < m-1) tot += a[i] + b[++j];
    while (i < n-1) tot += a[++i] + b[j];
        
    cout << tot << endl;
    return 0;
}
```